# Support Vector machine SVM python ValueError: X.shape[1]

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, svm, valueerror

I get the error:

"ValueError X.shape[1] = 2 should be equal to 3, the number of features at training time"

when I implement the last 4 lines of the code. I need one more future because I have this definition in beginning: X = train1.iloc[:, :3]. But I don't know how to do it.
What do I have to add in the last 4 lines to define one more feature?

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.svm import SVC



import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

train1 = pd.read_csv(train)


X = train1.iloc[:, :3]
y = train1.iloc[:,4]

C = 1.0 # SVM regularization parameter
svc = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1,).fit(X, y)

# create a mesh to plot in
x_min, x_max = X.iloc[:, 0].min() - 1, X.iloc[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X.iloc[:, 1].min() - 1, X.iloc[:, 1].max() + 1
h = (x_max / x_min)/100
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
 np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))

plt.subplot(1, 1,1)
Z = svc.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Paired, alpha=0.8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not complete, where does the svm come from? `import sklearn`

When you split your dataset into label and features

```
X = train1.iloc[:, :3]
y = train1.iloc[:,4]
```

are you intentionally ommiting the 3rd column? your X has 3 columns `[0,1,2]` and the Y is the 4th, the 3rd is missing. Maybe what you mean is:

```
X = train1.iloc[:, :4]
y = train1.iloc[:,4]
```

Comment: Yes you are right. But I still get the same error: ValueError: X.shape[1] = 2 should be equal to 4, the number of features at training time